# Html in Snippet not showing

Tags: sharepoint-designer, column, snippet, edit-mode-panel

I've created some *Rollup Details* site columns and include them in the page layout.

Then i found them in the snippet gallery and copy them into the Edit Mode Panel.
Exactly like how it's been done to the *Browser Details* one, but only the Browser Details ones which are the default columns show up on the page.
[image]
[image]

The HTML didn't even exist in the actual page.

Comment: I think that you shouldn't copy from one to another. the issue is probably coming from column not being recognized by the Rollup Details site columns

Comment: Thanks Alex, I didn't copy the snippet from one to another, I generate them from the snippet gallery and copy the generated html code from there. Is this not the way we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

We have to include the site column into the page layout, other wise it wont show.